# Constraint via Foreign Key

Tags: foreign-key, sqlite, constraint

I have the following schema in SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE calendars 
  ( 
     id    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
     title TEXT NOT NULL 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE entry_types 
  ( 
     id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
     red         INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK(red BETWEEN 0 AND 255), 
     green       INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK(green BETWEEN 0 AND 255), 
     blue        INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK(blue BETWEEN 0 AND 255), 
     description TEXT NOT NULL 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE entries 
  ( 
     id            INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
     calendar_id   INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     entry_type_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     date          TEXT NOT NULL, 
     FOREIGN KEY(calendar_id) REFERENCES calendars(id), 
     FOREIGN KEY(entry_type_id) REFERENCES entry_types(id), 
     UNIQUE(calendar_id, date) 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE calendars_entry_types 
  ( 
     calendar_id   INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     entry_type_id INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
     FOREIGN KEY(calendar_id) REFERENCES calendars(id), 
     FOREIGN KEY(entry_type_id) REFERENCES entry_types(id) 
  );
```

Each `entry_type` can only be used for one particular `calendar`, which is encoded as the `UNIQUE` constraint in the `calendars_entry_types` table, restricting that many-to-many pattern to only one-to-many.

> **SIDEBAR:** Originally I defined the `entry_type` table like this:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE entry_types 
>   ( 
>      id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
>      -- SNIP color & description columns 
>      calendar_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
>      FOREIGN KEY(calendar_id) REFERENCES calendars(id) 
>   );
> ```
>
> This obviated the need for the `calendars_entry_types` table but then the `calendar_id` data was in two places: in the row in `entries` and in the row in `entry_types`, so I decided to change. Perhaps this was the wrong decision? I needed to keep the `calendar_id` in the `entries` table in order to keep the `UNIQUE(calendar_id, date)` constraint. **/SIDEBAR**

This is all well and good, but I now have nothing preventing a situation like

```
INSERT INTO calendars (id, title) VALUES (1, 'test1'), (2, 'test2');
INSERT INTO entry_types (id, red, green, blue, description) VALUES (1, 0, 0, 0, 'entrytype1');

-- entry_type id 1 goes with calendar id 1
INSERT INTO calendars_entry_types (calendar_id, entry_type_id) VALUES (1, 1);

-- this shouldn't work... calendar 2 doesn't go with entry_type 1
INSERT INTO entries (calendar_id, entry_type_id, date) VALUES (2, 1, 'entry1');  -- (I know that's not a date but this is just an example...)
```

Is it possible to write a constraint that would prevent the insertion of rows to the `entries` table that match this query?

```
SELECT id 
FROM   entries 
WHERE  ( calendar_id, entry_type_id ) NOT IN (SELECT calendar_id, 
                                                     entry_type_id 
                                              FROM   calendars_entry_types);
```

If not, is there a better or alternative way to design my schema that takes the "each entry type is only valid for a certain calendar" constraint into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need some small changes. First add a `UNIQUE` constraint on `calendars_entry_types` (this is needed for the new foreign key below):

```
UNIQUE (calendar_id, entry_type_id)
```

Then remove these two foreign keys from `entries`:

```
FOREIGN KEY (calendar_id) REFERENCES calendars (id), 
FOREIGN KEY (entry_type_id) REFERENCES entry_types (id),
```

and replace them with a composite one:

```
FOREIGN KEY (calendar_id, entry_type_id)
    REFERENCES calendars_entry_types (calendar_id, entry_type_id),
```

Comment: Thank you! I was unaware of composite foreign keys until now.

Comment: Additional information for future reference: this didn't appear to work at first because SQLite as of version 3.6.19 [defaults to not enforcing foreign key constraints](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys). I had to enable them with `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` to prevent the insertion of "bad" rows.